# GUI takes two clicks to update sometimes?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm making a card game for and when cards are selected, the ImageIcon on the button is supposed to change. When I click them all in order they work just fine, but when I click them out of order it sometimes takes two clicks to update the image. How can I fix this issue so that it updates on the first click? Also, on a side note, is there a more efficient way for me to be updating the buttons besides making an if statement for every button? Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Board extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    Deck deck = new Deck();
    Card card;

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();

    JButton cardOne = new JButton();
    JButton cardTwo = new JButton();
    JButton cardThree = new JButton();
    JButton cardFour = new JButton();
    JButton cardFive = new JButton();
    JButton cardSix = new JButton();
    JButton cardSeven = new JButton();

    JButton[] buttons = {cardOne, cardTwo, cardThree, cardFour, cardFive, cardSix, cardSeven};

    int winCount = 0;
    int lossCount = 0;

    JButton replace = new JButton("Replace");
    JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
    JLabel cardsLeft = new JLabel("Cards left:" + deck.size());
    JLabel winLossLabel = new JLabel("Win: " + winCount + "\tLoss: " + lossCount);



    public Board() {
        initGUI();


    }

    ArrayList<Card> boardArray = new ArrayList<>();

    public void startGame() {
        deck.shuffle();
        Card card;

        for(int i = 0 ; i <=6 ; i++) {
            boardArray.add(card = deck.nextCard());
            buttons[i].setIcon(card.cardImage);

        }
        System.out.println(deck.toString());
    }
    public void initGUI() {
        setTitle("Elevens");
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,4));
        menuPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
        setResizable(false);

        buttonPanel.add(cardOne);
        buttonPanel.add(cardTwo);
        buttonPanel.add(cardThree);
        buttonPanel.add(cardFour);
        buttonPanel.add(cardFive);
        buttonPanel.add(cardSix);
        buttonPanel.add(cardSeven);

        menuPanel.add(replace);
        menuPanel.add(reset);
        menuPanel.add(cardsLeft);
        menuPanel.add(winLossLabel);

        add(buttonPanel);
        add(menuPanel);

        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
        }

        replace.setSize(new Dimension (100,10));

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600,300);

    }

    ImageIcon selectedIcon;
    Boolean selected = false;
    String newPathString;
    int buttonNumber;

    public void getPath(int buttonNumber) {

        String pathString = boardArray.get(buttonNumber).cardImage.toString();
        String path = "/Users/AlecRodgers/Documents/workspace/Elevens Lab Midyear Exam/src/";

        if(boardArray.get(buttonNumber).rank() == "Ace" || boardArray.get(buttonNumber).rank() == "Jack" || boardArray.get(buttonNumber).rank() == "Queen" || boardArray.get(buttonNumber).rank() == "King") {
            newPathString = path + boardArray.get(buttonNumber).rank() + boardArray.get(buttonNumber).suit() + "S.GIF";
        }else{
            newPathString = path + Integer.toString(boardArray.get(buttonNumber).pointValue()) + boardArray.get(buttonNumber).suit() + "S.GIF";
        }
        selectedIcon = new ImageIcon(newPathString);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == buttons) {

        }

        if(e.getSource() == cardOne) {
            if(selected == false) {
                getPath(0);
                buttons[0].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                selected = true;
            }else{
                selected = false;
                buttons[0].setIcon(boardArray.get(0).cardImage);
            }

        }
        if(e.getSource() == cardTwo) {
            if(selected == false) {
                getPath(1);
                buttons[1].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                selected = true;
            }else{
                selected = false;
                buttons[1].setIcon(boardArray.get(1).cardImage);
            }

        }
        if(e.getSource() == cardThree) {
            if(selected == false) {
                getPath(2);
                buttons[2].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                selected = true;
            }else{
                selected = false;
                buttons[2].setIcon(boardArray.get(2).cardImage);
            }

        }
        if(e.getSource() == cardFour) {
            if(selected == false) {
                getPath(3);
                buttons[3].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                selected = true;
            }else{
                selected = false;
                buttons[3].setIcon(boardArray.get(3).cardImage);
            }

        }
        if(e.getSource() == cardFive) {
            if(selected == false) {
                getPath(4);
                buttons[4].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                selected = true;
            }else{
                selected = false;
                buttons[4].setIcon(boardArray.get(4).cardImage);
            }

        }
        if(e.getSource() == cardSix) {
            if(selected == false) {
                getPath(5);
                buttons[5].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                selected = true;
            }else{
                selected = false;
                buttons[5].setIcon(boardArray.get(5).cardImage);
            }

        }
        if(e.getSource() == cardSeven) {
            if(selected == false) {
                getPath(6);
                buttons[6].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                selected = true;
            }else{
                selected = false;
                buttons[6].setIcon(boardArray.get(6).cardImage);
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: `Also, on a side note, is there a more efficient way for me to be updating the buttons besides making an if statement for every button?` Mhhh you're doing the same thing just with different numbers ... What do you think, wouldn't it make sense to use an integer variable instead of fixed numbers and set the value of this variable according to the pressed image/button?

Comment: @Tom That is what I was thinking, but how could I assign an int to each button?

Comment: For example with a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a different ActionListener to each JButton instead of sharing the same instance:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        final int index = i;
        final JButton b = buttons[index];
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                if (selected == false) {
                    getPath(index);
                    b.setIcon(selectedIcon);
                    selected = true;
                } else {
                    selected = false;
                    b.setIcon(boardArray.get(index).cardImage);
                }
            }
        });
}
```